# Yii2: Override global pdf orientation settings for mpdf in controller action

Tags: yii2, mpdf

I am using the mpdf extension to generate pdf files. I have set global settings for the mpdf in the config file, hence I am able to call the function every time I want to generate a pdf from my controller action. However, I am finding it hard to change the orientation for the pdf with data that requires landscape orientation since the default orientation set in the global settings is `portrait`. Here are the codes:

`main.pdf` code for the global setting

```
'pdf' => [
    'class' => Pdf::classname(),
    'mode' => Pdf::MODE_UTF8, // leaner size using standard fonts
    'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
    'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
    'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
    'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
    // any css to be embedded if required
    'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}',
    'options' => [
        'shrink_tables_to_fit' => 0
    ],
    // refer settings section for all configuration options
],
```

`Controller Action` calling the global settings:

```
public function actionReservationsList()
{
    $searchModel = new ReservationsSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->session->get('repquery'));
    $dataProvider->pagination = false;

    $pdf = Yii::$app->pdf;
    $pdf->content = $this->renderPartial('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    $pdf->methods = [
        'SetHeader' => [Yii::$app->user->identity->company->name.'||Date: ' . date("r")],
        'SetFooter' => ['User: '.Yii::$app->user->identity->username.'||Page {PAGENO}'],
    ];
    return $pdf->render();
}
```

So I need help in overriding the `'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,` setting that is in the global settings `main.php` file from the controller action.

Answer (score 1):

This work for me:

```
<?php
namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller; 
use kartik\mpdf\Pdf;

class InformesController extends Controller
{
   ...
    public function actionImprimirInforme($id,$key)
    {       
        $html = $this->renderPartial('informe-pdf', [ 
            'title' => 'Informe'
        ]);

        $pdf = new Pdf([
           'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
           'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_LANDSCAPE,
           'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
           'options' => [
               'showImageErrors' => true,
            ]
        ]);

        $pdf->configure([
            'title' => 'Informe ',
        ]);

        $pdf->content = $html; 

        $pdf->orientation = Pdf::ORIENT_LANDSCAPE;
        $pdf->execute('SetFooter', ['{PAGENO} de {nbpg}']);
        $pdf->filename = "Informe.pdf";
        return $pdf->render();
    }
}
```

---

My first answer was wrong, i have been setting the property 'orientation' into pdf component, so the dynamically assign does not work properly.

[Here you have the documentation example](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-mpdf)

Comment: Can you add an explaination of what you changed and why this should works ?

Comment: I add my main.php to the answer

Comment: i just change my answer, i hope helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the contents via addPage. So if you build a array of pages, with the contents etc - you should be able to specify the orientation per page.

```
<?php

$mpdf = new mPDF('', 'Legal');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('
    Hello World
');

$mpdf->AddPage('L'); // Adds a new page in Landscape orientation

$mpdf->WriteHTML('
    Hello World
');

$mpdf->Output();

?>
```

Comment: Yii2 is just a framework, the PDF creation is done by (in this case) mPDF. So no, its not. But you are using mPDF which is (i assume) implemented in Yii in some way. So it might be helpful to check if you have functions available like **'AddPage'** and work from there.

Comment: Actually I tried that but it is throwing an error that such a function is not available. Thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this line this :

```
$pdf = Yii::$app->pdf;
$pdf->orientation = Pdf::ORIENT_LANDSCAPE;
```